# Interpreter from venv not visible for selection

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I have a MacBook Pro m1 so I installed Python 3.6 by pyenv on my Mac. But, when I create venv by proprietary package on PyCharm and I go to select interpreter from here, PyCharm does nothing. In other words, I select Python 3.6 from my venv, but PyCharm still has no interpreter.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to execute the interpreter from command line. Note: you cannot mix ARM and Intel modules/libraries in the same executable (sometime this is a problem on M1, in such case you must install also a parallel Intel version of python)\

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi command line has python 3.6 by pyenv. I can't install intel version with parallel. Also I have used parallel to virtualize ubuntu, but when I installed requirements, I got a compile error of pandas dependencies and libraries.

Comment: On my M1 I use conda (miniconda), and so I can have different python version, and also different architectures. In any case my question was: what happens if you execute the python interpreter as you gave it in pycharm (without starting it with pyenv). This may get you some hints on the real problem

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi but miniconda create a venv itself. My procedure is that:
1. I install python 3.6 for installing proprietary package. 
2. open project in pycharm and install venv with proprietary package ( for do this, i need python 3.6 on terminal).
3. select pycharm interpreter from venv

Comment: @bad_coder yes, I didn't see filters. Now works. Thanks.

Comment: TO REOPEN REVIEWERS: As you can see this post is about a separate and isolated problem, while the other thread is about configuring/adding interpreters; this thread is about a specific control in the UI that needs to be turned off. (This thread is also about an issue that happens in multi-project environments, something that isn't the topic of the other thread.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to uncheck a filter in the Python interpreter's dialogue for the venv to become visible. (See the dialogue in point 3 of the PyCharm documentation - [Modify a Python interpreter﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#modify_interpreter)).

Go to  `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Python Interpreter` `>` click the Cog icon `>` Select `Show All...` `>` Unselect the filter icon that reads: `Hide virtual environments associated with other projects`, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Python interpreter's dialogue in PyCharm]